# How can I store a private api key in a source file?

Tags: php

I have an open-source project on github that, amongst other things, communicates with the github API to get information.

It's working fine, but I'll need to use at least basic authentication, due to the potential number of calls to the site.

I don't want users of my script to have to create their own API keys just to use this, so I'd like to just generate my own key and use that. Is there a way of storing the key in the php source file so that people accessing the source won't see it?

Comment: No. (comment not long enough)

Comment: It would be better if you required them to create their own API keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot both distribute a private key and intend to keep it private.

Furthermore, from your description users of your code *should* create their own private keys, that way requests made against the API are done by their accounts, and you don't get targeted for any sort of abuse they might carry out.